# BSOD doing wireless connection repair

Tags: wireless-networking, bsod

(This should maybe be asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/beta-access), but currently it is only for beta users.)
We have a Dell Latitude X1 which always gets a BSOD (page fault in non page area)
 after repair on wireless.
Wireless works as long as we do not do repair.
Have tried the following with no success:
Have updated BIOS to latest version and updated drivers for Intel wireless to the latest version.
Any other suggestions?
For now we just do not do repair and maybe that is the solution?

Comment: Superuser public beta password: ewok.adventure

Comment: You should do a dump analysis, in that way we provide you with better help. Do you know how?

Answer (score 2):

Few things -

First do a memory test to rule it out as it is the most common problem related to "Page Fault in Non Paged Area"

I recommend using [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/)

If you have ruled this out and it is not a problem with memory, try updating your network driver. you have not provided a lot of information and not sure on your OS, but I know I had problems with a few clients relating to the network stack and unfortunately nothing fixed it (other than upgrading to 7 which seemed to fix it).